# swagger-core v3 ignore my configurations in javax.ws.rs.core.Application

Tags: java, rest, swagger, openapi

Using swagger-core v3 2.1.6 these three configurations produce same openapi.json result.

No configuration:

```
@ApplicationPath("/rest")
public class AuthRestConfig extends Application {

  public AuthRestConfig() {

  }
}
```

Server Configuration, I need to use this kind of conf:

```
@ApplicationPath("/rest")
public class AuthRestConfig extends Application {

  public AuthRestConfig(@Context ServletConfig servletConfig) {
    super();

    OpenAPI oas = new OpenAPI();
    Info info = new Info()
        .title("Suma Automaton OpenAPI")
        .description("This is a sample server Petstore server.  You can find out more about Swagger "
            + "at [http://swagger.io](http://swagger.io) or on [irc.freenode.net, #swagger](http://swagger.io/irc/).  For this sample, "
            + "you can use the api key `special-key` to test the authorization filters.")
        .termsOfService("http://swagger.io/terms/")
        .contact(new Contact()
            .email("baldodavi@gmail.com"));

    oas.info(info);

    String url = "/suma-automaton-ms";
    List<Server> servers = new ArrayList<>();
    Server server = new Server();
    server.setUrl(url);
    servers.add(server);
    oas.setServers(servers);

    SwaggerConfiguration oasConfig = new SwaggerConfiguration()
        .openAPI(oas)
        .prettyPrint(true)
        .resourcePackages(Stream.of("io.swagger.sample.resource").collect(Collectors.toSet()));

    try {
      new JaxrsOpenApiContextBuilder<>()
          .servletConfig(servletConfig)
          .application(this)
          .openApiConfiguration(oasConfig)
          .buildContext(true);
    } catch (OpenApiConfigurationException e) {
      throw new RuntimeException(e.getMessage(), e);
    }

  }
}
```

Any suggestion about this behavior? Is there something I misunderstood? Consider I've the same behaviour also using standard configuration reported in https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-core/wiki/Swagger-2.X---Integration-and-configuration#jax-rs-application

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your AuthRestConfig class:

```
import io.swagger.v3.jaxrs2.integration.resources.OpenApiResource;

@Override
public Set<Class<?>> getClasses() {
    Set<Class<?>> resources = new HashSet<>();

    resources.add(OpenApiResource.class);

    return resources;
}
```